# Do I need to inform in-process recruitment of employment changes?

Tags: recruitment, employer-relations, human-resources

I am currently involved in recruitment with a large company, which (I think) is in final stages after about a month of multiple interviews and a flight out to headquarters.

Last week (July 31) I left my then-company on good terms to pursue other opportunities, however when I first applied to this *new* company I was still employed.

Effectively, when I applied my resume listed my tenure like `January 2010 - Present` but, now, it should accurately be `January 2010 - August 2013`

**Do I need to inform the recruiter of this development?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The change of status will be important in three areas:

1. They will want to know why you left. For some reasons it will not cause an issue (loss of contract). For other reasons it may cause them to reconsider (fired). I have seen a trend that they want to document every change of company. They will also be confirmed during the last background check.
2. It will also be important if they are conducting a government required background investigation, all positions and gaps in employment will need to documented. Update the recruiter to minimize last minute glitches.
3. Starting date. They typically expect that there will be a gap between when you receive the offer letter, and the start date. This is to cover notice period requirements. For countries with significant notice periods this can make a big difference. This could give you an advantage over another candidate. You might even tell them before your last day.

One reason not to tell them would be that it weakens your bargaining position. If they know you have no income you will be less likely to demand a salary at the high end of the range. You wouldn't dare make a counter offer. Of course reasons number 1 & 2 may force you to tell them.